# Push and Pop in a single button in windows application

Tags: windows, winforms

Currently I am working in a windows application,and the requirement is I have a button so when first time i click, it need to be behave like it is pushed and when next time i will click the same button it need to be behave like pop.

Comment: you are talking about GUI changes, right ?

Comment: Yes I mean a button when 1st time clicked it will show a grid with some information and the button look like it is pushed and when next time clicked to same button the grid will disappear and button will look like pop (mean to normal stage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a check box and making its appearance property to button and use it as button.
I think this may help you.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox1.Text = "Pop";
            MessageBox.Show("Data Pushed into the stack");
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Text = "Push";
            MessageBox.Show("Data Poped from the stack");
        }
    }
```

This will work as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global boolean variable that will change on Button click. Every time when button click event fires, just check for the boolean status. And the same button can work as ON/OFF mode.

```
Private isStarted As Boolean = False

Private Sub OnStartButtonClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    If (isStarted = False) Then
        isStarted = True
        btnStart.Text = "Stop"

        'DO YOUR WORK'
    Else
        isStarted = False
        btnStart.Text = "Start"

        'DO YOUR WORK'
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding condition in the same button click.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.Text == "Push")
    {
        button1.Text = "Pop";
        MessageBox.Show("Data Pushed into the stack");
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Text = "Push";
        MessageBox.Show("Data Popedfrom the stack");
    }
}
```

Initially make button1.Text as "Push", When it is clicked, do your Push operation and change the name to "Pop",
When the button1.Text is "Pop", do your popping operation and change the name to "Push".
Hope you understand...

Comment: no this is not what i am looking for, i need some button properties to be changed when 1st time it is clicked ,and the button is look like the button is pressed and second time when i will click it will look like it is a normal button and the button is not selected.